# Oracle query with regex to find records

Tags: regex, oracle

I have to find all the records have leading or trailing spaces as well as records having underscore(_) with leading or trailing spaces in between the string from a table having a column as shown below:-

Note:- * is representing an space.

```
place_id    place_name
----------- --------------------
1           *Bilaspur
2           Jaipur*
3           Madhya*Pradesh
4           State*of*Tamilnaddu
5           **Kangra
6           Chandigrah**
7           Himachal_*Pradesh
8           Utar*_Pradesh
```

From above table using regex oracle query I have to find out all the records except place id 3 and 4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yet another option:

```
SQL> with test (place_id, place_name) as
  2    (select 1, ' Bilaspur'           from dual union
  3     select 2, 'Jaipur '             from dual union
  4     select 3, 'Madhya Pradesh'      from dual union
  5     select 4, 'State of Tamilnaddu' from dual union
  6     select 5, '  Kangra'            from dual union
  7     select 6, 'Chandigrah  '        from dual union
  8     select 7, 'Himachal_ Pradesh'   from dual union
  9     select 8, 'Utar _Pradesh'       from dual
 10    )
 11  select * from test
 12  where regexp_like(place_name, '^ | $|_ | _');

  PLACE_ID PLACE_NAME
---------- -------------------
         1  Bilaspur
         2 Jaipur
         5   Kangra
         6 Chandigrah
         7 Himachal_ Pradesh
         8 Utar _Pradesh

6 rows selected.

SQL>
```

Such an expression returns values that

- start with a space `^` or `|`
- ends with a space  `$` or `|`
- contains an underline `_`

Comment: This does not test for "underscore(_) with leading or trailing spaces" it just checks for an underscore regardless of the adjacent characters.

Comment: Aha; I misunderstood the question, thought that it is an underscore that matters (not spaces around it). I fixed it (at least, I hope so). Thank you, @MT0.

Answer (score 2):

If the name of the table is `A`, then you might want to try:

```
Select * from A where REGEXP_LIKE(place_name,'^\s|\s$|\s_|_\s','i')
```

**[Click for regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/KS95Tg/1/)**

**Explanation:**

- `^\s` - matches a white-space after the start of the line
- `|` - OR
- `\s$` - matches a white-space before the end of the line
- `|` - OR
- `\s_` - matches a white-space before an `_`
- `|` - OR
- `_\s` - matches a white-space after an `_`

Also see the [Reference](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B13789_01/server.101/b10759/conditions018.htm#SQLRF00501)

Answer (score 2):

You don't need regular expressions:

```
SELECT *
FROM   table_name
WHERE  place_name LIKE ' %'
OR     place_name LIKE '% '
OR     place_name LIKE '% \_%' ESCAPE '\'
OR     place_name LIKE '%\_ %' ESCAPE '\';
```